# What in ExtJS 5.1.1 fixed the bug that BufferedStore with remoteFilter and remoteSort calls the first page twice when filtering?

Tags: javascript, extjs, store, extjs5

If you run this code in Ext 5.1.0.107, you'll see 2 get request for the first page. When you run it in 5.1.1.451, you'll see just 1 get request.

What was done to fix this?

Reason I'm asking that I cannot upgrade Ext right now and I need to fix it in my version (that is actually 5.0.0).

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.BufferedStore', {
            proxy: {
                type: 'rest',
                url : '/test'
            },
            autoLoad: false,
            autoSync: false,

            remoteFilter: true,
            remoteSort:   true,

            fields: ['name']
        });

        var filterStore = function() {
            store.filter([{
                id       : 1,
                property : 'name',
                value    : 'test'
            }]);
        }

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'top',
                items: [{
                    type    : 'button',
                    text    : 'Filter store',
                    handler : filterStore
                }]
            }],
            store: store,
            columns: [
                { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' }
            ],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

([fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rci))

[image]

Comment: According to this: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?289047 ... Yeah this was a bug.

Comment: You can write to Sencha support and they will give you an override.

Comment: @PawełGłowacz Nice find. But according to the top of the page, the fix was applied in 5.0.2. And I am observing the erratic behaviour in 5.1.0. I can try it Monday.